# Incorrect sum from joining two table having similar columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given i have two tables `A` and `B`. These two tables have certain common columns say `col1` and `col2`. Now what i am trying to get is sum from `A` and sum from `B` together. Following is the query i am using at the moment.

```
select 
col1 as W_NAME, 
col2 as I_NAME, 
NVL(sum(a.accepted),0) as RECEIVED_QTY,
NVL(sum(b.issue),0) as ISSUE_QTY

from TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b
where a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2
group by col1, col2
```

Data is stored in tables in following format.

```
TABLE1

col1       col2          accepted
data1      val1          500
data1      val1          200
data2      val1          300
data2      val2          200

TABLE2

col1       col2          issue
data1      val1          100
data1      val1          50
data2      val2          100
```

I am trying to get the data in following format,

```
col1     col2    accepted    issue
data1    val1     700        150
data2    val1     300        0
data2    val2     200        100
```

In my query i am either missing some rows or the sum displayed is messed up. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: you need to perform the sum and then join

Comment: Thanks alot man, i just havent had my coffee yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with TABLE1_sum as (
select 
col1 as W_NAME, 
col2 as I_NAME, 
NVL(sum(a.accepted),0) as RECEIVED_QTY
from TABLE1 a
group by W_NAME, I_NAME
),
TABLE2_sum as (
select 
col1 as W_NAME, 
col2 as I_NAME, 
NVL(sum(b.issue),0) as ISSUE_QTY
from TABLE2 b
group by W_NAME, I_NAME
)
select coalesce(a.W_NAME,b.W_NAME) as W_NAME,
       coalesce(a.I_NAME,b.I_NAME) as I_NAME,
       coalesce(RECEIVED_QTY,0) as RECEIVED_QTY,
       coalesce(ISSUE_QTY,0) as ISSUE_QTY
from TABLE1_sum
full outer join TABLE2_sum on a.W_NAME = b.W_NAME and a.I_NAME = b.I_NAME
```